# How to rotate Text 90 degree anti clock wise in PPTX from python

Tags: python, rotation, powerpoint

I have tried to rotate the text in the powerpoint slide 90 degree anticlock wise but it's rotated clock wise or stay horizntal only any one can help meee

````
HF_Text = slide.shapes.add_textbox(
            left=Bar1_Left - Inches(0.1),
            top=Bar1_Top + Bar1_height/3.3,
            width=Inches(0.1),  # Adjust the width as needed
            height=Inches(0.1),  # Adjust the height as needed
        ).text_frame
        Text3 = HF_Text.paragraphs[0]
        Text3.text = "VLF & LF & MF"
        Text3.font.size = Pt(10)
        Text3.font.bold = True  # Set the bold property to True
        

#HF_Text.rotation = -90

#HF_Text._bodyPr.attrib.update({'vert': 'vert', 'rot': '-90'})

    ```
````